# Errors while building APK. You can find the errors in the 'Messages' view. this is my error

Tags: xml, android-studio, debugging

it was going good suddenly I get an error while generating apk.

I tried all the solutions like invalidate cache restart, rebuild project, clean projet disable instant but it does not work. kindly provide me a solution

> here is my project level Gradle file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.31'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
//        mavenCentral()
//        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

> this is my Gradle file (app level)  is there something wrong

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.e_pick_n_drop"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.firebase:geofire-android:3.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    //implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    //annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    //implementation 'com.github.karanchuri:PermissionManager:0.1.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'

}
```

> this is the output of build output I didn't understand the problem kindly 
>   give me an appropriate solution

```
.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformationStep] Transforming artifact play-services-location.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0) with JetifyTransform
18:09:31.693 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformationStep] Transforming artifact play-services-location.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0) with ExtractAarTransform
18:09:31.693 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformationStep] Transforming artifact play-services-location.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0) with AarTransform
18:09:31.693 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformationStep] Transforming artifact legacy-support-v4.aar (androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0) with JetifyTransform
18:09:31.693 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformationStep] Transforming artifact legacy-support-v4.aar (androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0) with ExtractAarTransform
18:09:31.693 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformationStep] Transforming artifact legacy-support-v4.aar (androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0) with AarTransform
18:09:31.694 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformationStep] Transforming artifact firebase-messaging.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0) with JetifyTransform
18:09:31.694 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformationStep] Transforming artifact firebase-messaging.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0) with ExtractAarTransform
18:09:31.694 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformationStep] Transforming artifact firebase-messaging.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0) with AarTransform
18:09:31.694 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformationStep] Transforming artifact recyclerview.aar (androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0) with JetifyTransform
18:09:31.694 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformationStep] Transforming artifact recyclerview.aar (androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0) with ExtractAarTransform
18:09:31.694 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformationStep] Transforming artifact recyclerview.aar (androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0) with AarTransform
18:09:31.694 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformationStep] Transforming artifact recyclerview.aar (androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0) with JetifyTransform
18:09:31.694 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformationStep] Transforming artifact recyclerview.aar (androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0) with ExtractAarTransform
18:09:31.695 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformationStep] Transforming artifact recyclerview.aar (androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0) with AarTransform
18:09:31.695 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformationStep] Transforming artifact recyclerview.aar (androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0) with JetifyTransform
18:09:31.695 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformationStep] Transforming artifact recyclerview.aar (androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0) with ExtractAarTransform
18:09:31.695 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformationStep] Transforming artifact recyclerview.aar (androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0) with AarTransform
18:09:31.695 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformationStep] Transforming artifact circleimageview.aar (de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0) with JetifyTransform
18:09:31.695 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformationStep] Transforming artifact circleimageview.aar (de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0) with ExtractAarTransform
18:09:31.696 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformationStep] Transforming artifact circleimageview.aar (de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0) with AarTransform
18:09:31.696 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformationStep] Transforming artifact play-services-flags.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-flags:17.0.0) with JetifyTransform
18:09:31.696 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformationStep] Transforming artifact play-services-flags.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-flags:17.0.0) with ExtractAarTransform
18:09:31.696 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformationStep] Transforming artifact play-services-flags.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-flags:17.0.0) with AarTransform
18:09:31.696 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformationStep] Transforming artifact firebase-auth-interop.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-interop:18.0.0) with JetifyTransform
18:09:31.696 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformationStep] Transforming artifact firebase-auth-interop.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-interop:18.0.0) with ExtractAarTransform
18:09:31.696 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformationStep] Transforming artifact firebase-auth-interop.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-interop:18.0.0) with AarTransform
18:09:31.696 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformationStep] Transforming artifact firebase-auth-interop.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-interop:18.0.0) with JetifyTransform
18:09:31.697 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformationStep] Transforming artifact firebase-auth-interop.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-interop:18.0.0) with ExtractAarTransform
```